# What is JSONArray,JSONObject,JSONStringer and JSONTokenizer

Tags: android, json

I'm new to Android. I have learnt some basic concepts in Android. Now I'm learning **JSON**, I wanted to know the definitions of **JSONArray,JSONObject,JSONStringer and JSONTokenizer**. I'm a bit confused with these terms.Can anyone provide me the correct definition for these terms??

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the docs for [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), [JSONStringer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer.html) and [JSONTokenizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html)?

Answer (score 1):

**json array:**

```
 [
   {
      "id":711
   },   {
      "id":712
   }
]
```

**json object:**

```
 {
      "id":711
   }
```

**1)** **Array([)**
In a JSON file , square bracket **([)** represents a JSON array.

**2)**  **Objects({)**
In a JSON file, curly bracket **({)** represents a JSON object.

**3)**  **Key**
A JSON object contains a key that is just a string. Pairs of key/value make up a JSON object.

**4)**  **Value**
Each key has a value that could be string , integer or double e.t.c

see more detailed explanation here:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: I have looked into it, But it does not give you the complete picture.